# Dissociate Control-I and Tabulation

Tags: shell, console, shortcut

In a shell, pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key sends the <kbd>Control-I</kbd> keycode.
Is there any way or hack to dissociate them in a shell?

I would like to have two distinct behaviours depending on whether I type <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Control-I</kbd> but so far I could not figure out a way to do this without remapping the "i" key.